# Sublime on Mac: No such file or directory

Tags: python, macos, sublimetext2

While trying to download opencv to use it with python in sublime, I think I may have messed something up. Now, even the most simple command returns this is REPL:

> python: posix_spawn: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No such file or directory
>
> ***Repl Closed***

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing that executable file that I think is installed with Python (I have it on my Mac as well).  Try uninstalling then reinstalling Python.